# How do I update Rating Control in GridView column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress-mvc

I want to update the control Rating in disabled if bit Evaluacion is false, but there is no action. I use the HtmlDataCellPrepared property to modify the column but I can not make it a column disabled, I need to disable the control but I do not know how I could do it.

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Name = "Evaluacion";
        column.Caption = "Evaluacion";
        column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(container =>
        {
            @Html.DevExpress().RatingControl(linkSettings =>
           {
               linkSettings.Name = "RatingControl_" + container.KeyValue;
               linkSettings.ClientSideEvents.ItemClick = "function(s, e){ Eval(s, e, " + container.KeyValue + "); }";
               linkSettings.Enabled = true;
           }).GetHtml();
        });
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "bitEvaluacion";
    });
    settings.HtmlDataCellPrepared = (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.DataColumn.Name == "Evaluacion")
        {
            bool bitEvaluacion = Convert.ToBoolean(e.GetValue("bitEvaluacion"));
            if (bitEvaluacion == false)
            {
                e.DataColumn.ReadOnly = true;
                e.Cell.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    };
```

Control is still enabled after the bitEvaluacion cell is set to "True"
[image: Control is still enabled after the bitEvaluacion cell is set to "True"]

Comment: Are you mean to "disable rating control in any GridView cells where `bitEvaluacion` column value is set to false"? Can you provide sample grid image to illustrate your needs?

Comment: Of course, I already added the image of the table.